# Wordpress: Using relative URLs in the Menu using Custom Links

Tags: wordpress

When I try to use relative URLs when creating menus in Wordpress...Wordpress always prepends "http://" to the relative path after I click Save. How do I prevent Wordpress from prepending the "http://" in the URL field?

I think I read to change a bit of code in wp-includes/nav-menu.php, but I'd prefer not changing any core code...just in functions.php if necessary.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you expand a little?  Are you saying it's adding the full URL, including the path, and then another version of your path?  Such as:  www.site.com/path/path?  Or are you seeing www.site.com/path as is the actual end URL?

Comment: I'm sorry, I need to revise/clarify my original question. I'm trying to create a relative path in my Menu Custom Link, (e.g. path/). When I click Save, it prepends it with http:// and saves it as http://path/

Comment: I just tested this, and it seems to work fine for me.  If you use the "Custom Link" option, remove the placeholder "http://" text and just type in the relative URL, it should work fine.  When you view it in a browser, it will add the absolute path though, that is expected.  Make sure you type your URL like so:   /path/ - a trailing slash is not necessary but you can add if you want.

Comment: Thanks for trying it! But I'm actually trying to use a relative URL without the first /. For example: path/ or ./  In these examples, WordPress would prepend the http:// to it.